# Bounding difference of Matrix products

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, convergence-divergence, random-matrices

I am trying to bound the following expression
$$||\frac{1}{N} W^TQW - \lambda \mathbf{1}_N||_F~,$$
where $W\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times m }$ with $||W||_{\text{op}} \leq \sqrt{N} C'$, $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N }$ a **diagonal matrix** with $||Q||_{\text{op}} \leq \sqrt{N} C$, $\lambda = \frac{1}{N} \text{tr} Q$ and $m/N\to 0$ for $N\to\infty$. I know that $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}}||W - W_0||_F\leq cN^{-1/2}$, where the entries $(W_0)_{ij}$ of the reference matrix $W_0$ are iid random variables drawn from a normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

My unsuccessful approach was
$$||\frac{1}{N} W^TQW - \lambda \mathbf{1}_N||_F\leq ||\frac{1}{N} W_0^TQW_0 - \lambda \mathbf{1}_N||_F + ||\frac{1}{N} W^TQW - \frac{1}{N} W_0^TQW_0||_F~,$$

The first part can be bounded with high probability using Markov inequality. I tried to bound the second term as follows:
$$ ||\frac{1}{N} W^TQW - \frac{1}{N} W_0^TQW_0||_F \leq 2 ||Q||_{op} \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}}||W||_{op} \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}}||W - W_0||_F~.$$
However, the last expression on the right hand side above does not go to zero because $||Q||_{op}\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{N}}||W - W_0||_F$ can be bounded to be less or equal to a constant $cC$.

I am puzzled, because in the expression to be bound the dimension $m$ is fixed and does not go to $\infty$, so my assumption is that it should go to zero with high probability as well.

Does somebody have an idea what property to analyze or how to proceed?

Thanks in advanced!

**Update**
I the meantime I played with the expressions above. I still believe the bound holds, however, the presented bound and estimates may be not tight enough to proof the desired result. In case that I will find a solution to the problem in future I let you know.

Comment: Is $W_0$ a random matrix? If so, then the bound $\| W - W_0 \|$ should hold with a certain probability. If $W_0$ is not a random matrix, then you cannot use the Markov inequality and high probability bounds to obtain the bounds on the first matrix.

Comment: @sudeep5221 yes it is a random matrix, with entries drawn from a standard normal distribution.